# Heroku crashes with error "bash: line 1: app/main:app: No such file or directory"

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-api

I have a Django app that I am hosting on Heroku connected via Github.  However, every time I try to start the app, I am receiving the error `app[uvicorn.1]: bash: line 1: app/main:app: No such file or directory`.

Looking up the problem, it seems that it is in the wrong directory, but even changing the `app/main:app` location still gives the same error.

The Procfile contents are: `uvicorn app/main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT}`.

I have attached a screenshot of the file hierarchy as well to help understand the structure.

[image]

I tried changing the Procfile to `uvicorn main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT}` but still received the error: `bash: line 1: main:app: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

After more research, I found that I had formed the Procfile incorrectly.  The correct format is `web: uvicorn app.main:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT:-5000}`

The following article was helpful.
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-deploy-your-fastapi-app-on-heroku-for-free-8d4271a4ab9